# Why wikipedia use a second html anchor when the id contains special characters

Tags: html, anchor, special-characters, wikipedia

Wikipedia recommends to provide a manual anchor when special characters are used within an attribute id, especially when it is used as an [anchor](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Astuces/Ancre) (sorry it seems to be in french only).

Concerning this recommendations, I have two questions:

- Is it to support a specific browser or all browsers? I couldn't find any information about such issue
- What is the encoding format/language used in the content "Encres_.C3.A0_.C3.A9crire_et_dessiner"?. Could we use html entities instead?

Example: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encre#Encres_%C3%A0_%C3%A9crire_et_dessiner

```html
<span id="Encres_.C3.A0_.C3.A9crire_et_dessiner"></span>
<span class="mw-headline" id="Encres_à_écrire_et_dessiner">Encres à écrire et dessiner</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backwards compatibility for the legacy ID format that was used in the HTML4 times. HTML4 only allowed a handful of non-alphanumeric characters in IDs. The format is like [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) but with dot instead of percent sign (which is also not allowed), plus dots themselves did not get encoded (unlike percent signs in percent encoding), making this format somewhat broken.